# ListView rounded corner hidden by list item's background image in android

Tags: android

[image][image: Using Padding...][image: When Screen Called]I have given border to listview .
and also give the background images in list item.
so due to list item's background image listview's border hidden.

listview

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewsea"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cornerborder"
        >
    </ListView>
```

cornerborder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#457DB6" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:endColor="#457DB6"
        android:startColor="#457DB6" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

In listAdapter

```
if(position%2 == 0)
            {
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.commonrow_type_1_straight);

            }else 
            {
                                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.commonrow_type_2_straight);

            }
```

Comment: which image? What XML layout code are you trying?

Comment: @PareshMayani i have used xml for listview corner and for list row i have used images in ListAdapter.

Comment: @PareshMayani i have set  android:paddingBottom="5dp" but not look good listview ...kindly sugggest any solution for this.

Comment: instead of cornerborder.xml, what if you prepare image and place it as a border? FYI, you can create 9-patch border image with rounded or any curveture

Comment: ok but thing is list item's background image hide listviews bottom

Comment: The behaviour you are seeing is exactly what you should expect.  The way android draws backgrounds means that the item background is always drawn over the list's background. There's really not much you can do about it except checking in your adapter whether the list item being requested is the last one to be displayed and, if yes, using a different background, with transparent bottom corners.

Comment: You can try having padding in your listitem's xml file.

Comment: @Hiral i have also try tht but as 1 st screen shot but not look good

Comment: Try giving padding to your listview.it worked for me.

Comment: @Hiral i have atteched padding image ...

Comment: @parag: you just need to little left and right padding,no need of top and bottom,i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank God Finally Got Solution........
here XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/lineargallarybackground"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textlisttitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/titlebackground"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="Kuwait" >
        </TextView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewsea"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
            android:clipChildren="true"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ListView>
     </LinearLayout>
```

I have set background image in Linearlayout .

Answer (score 0):

If anyone (like me) is looking for a solution that pushes the listview **right to the edge of the rounding** without adding padding, this should do the trick:

Try subclassing ListView (or a containing layout) and overriding the OnDraw method as follows, substituting in values for RADIUS_IN_PIXELS:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path clipPath = new Path();
    clipPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(canvas.getClipBounds()), RADIUS_IN_PIXELS, RADIUS_IN_PIXELS, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

...and also create a custom drawable like this called something like 'rounded', substituting in YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR and RADIUS_IN_DP, making sure to match the rounding of the rectangle in DP to your previous clipping radius in PX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="RADIUS_IN_DP" />
    <solid android:color="YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR"/>
</shape>
```

Then you can use that subclass in your layout, adding the following lines to your ListView or containing layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded"
android:clipChildren="true"
```

All children will clip to the bounds you specify in the OnDraw() override, and a background will be added based on your 'rounded' drawable.