# Android Listview item image rounded corners

Tags: android, android-layout

My android listview row contain a image and some description, i need the image to have rounded corners

Comment: Duplicate! Read this question to get what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners

Comment: I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767917/listview-rounded-corner-hidden-by-list-items-background-image-in-android

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blog.gunawan.me/2012/03/create-semi-transparent-rounded-border.html) is the Solution . Create Semi Transparent Rounded Border Image in Android